# Using Arch Linux computer as a server for Rack Apps

Tags: web-server, arch-linux, ruby-rack

What would be the best way to go about using an Arch Linux computer as a Rack (as in Ruby Rack, not an actual rack server) server? Here's what I want to be able to do:

1. Automatically deploy on a git push to the server. (I already have this worked out, on post-receive the server checks out the app to `/home/git/app` from `/home/git/app.git`.)
2. Run a Rack server application to serve up this app, one that can be restarted on demand.
3. Run a MongoDB server
4. Be able to access the app by going to my-server.local/app or something similar. (It's really only going to be used on the local network, no port forwarding or outside use)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I apologize if this seems too "do it for me".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is rather "do it for me" -- most of what you still need to do is write some shell scripts to automate things in your local environment.  For running the rack apps, I use daemontools in combination with [allah](https://github.com/anchor/allah) to make restarting easier, and I use [giddyup](https://github.com/mpalmer/giddyup) to do all my `git push` deployment easier.  The rest is all locally-written scripts.